# Web Service Debugger Exception : Undefined complexType 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array'

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging a web service and only the first time I connect to it I get this exception on the DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx(?) class (take a look at the path)
[image]

Now it seems to be related to compliance of the basic profile 1.1 but I have that turned off in the config file.

`<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <conformanceWarnings>
        <remove name='BasicProfile1_1'/>
      </conformanceWarnings>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

If I disable exceptions and let it run it finally goes thru after blowing up 4 times in the same place. After that I can go on and debug the application just fine.
This is annoying me, specially because I haven't had this problem before and I don't know how to get rid of it. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not happening anymore after a December update of Windows. On another online forum it seems somebody had this resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling IIS. The problem seems to be related to AppPools targeting 4.0 Framework.

Is not happening anymore... magic in the air :)